# FCC ESP32 S2 MINI 2 Module

Tags: esp32, fcc

We found a failure in the ESP32 S2 MINI2 Module FCC-RSE testing. Below are the images of the failure peak(2.4835GHz) in 11g testing.

[image: Radiated test results]

After the failure, if we set the attenuation with 24 means 6dB, then we can pass the device. Please let me know if this is the correct way to proceed as it will reduce the Tx power. We need to use full Tx for our application. Kindly let us know of any solution to mitigate this failure with full Tx power.